# Issue with DISTINCT or GROUP BY on multiple Columns in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, distinct-values

I am using PHP and MYSQL to populate some dropdown lists from a database.

However, I have been at my wits end as to why the following query populates only the first column (City) - and that too without grouping,  specified from the bunch of columns that needs to be grouped

```
SELECT City, NativeTown, Language, State 
FROM candidates 
WHERE ApprovalCode!='' AND Gender='$gtype' 
GROUP BY City, NativeTown, Language, State 
ORDER BY City,NativeTown,State,Language ASC
```

I tried this too

```
SELECT DISTINCT City, NativeTown, Language, State 
FROM candidates 
WHERE ApprovalCode!='' AND Gender='$gtype' 
ORDER BY City,NativeTown,State,Language ASC
```

But, in both, only City gets populated and that too without grouping

Where am I going wrong ?

PS:

Database

[image]

ACTUAL CODE

```
$getC=$maindb->query("SELECT City, NativeTown, Language, State FROM candidates 
WHERE ApprovalCode!='' AND Gender='$gtype' 
GROUP BY City, NativeTown, Language, State 
ORDER BY City,NativeTown,State,Language ASC") or die("LIST ERROR :".$maindb->error);


    City<br>
        <!-- <input type="text" name="city" id="city" Placeholder="City" <?php //if(isset($filtvals['city'])){echo "Value ='$filtvals[city]'";}?>>-->

        <select name="city" id="city">
                <option value="Choose">Choose</option>
                <?php while($getClist=$getC->fetch_assoc()){?>
                <option value="<?php  echo $getClist['City'];?>" <?php if(isset($filtvals['city']) && $filtvals['city']==$getClist['City']){echo "Selected='Selected'";}?>><?php  echo $getClist['City'];?></option>
                <?php } $e=error_get_last(); print_r($e);?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div>State<br>
        <select name="State" id="State">
                <option value="Choose">Choose</option>
        <?php while($getClist=$getC->fetch_assoc()){?>
                    <option value="<?php  echo $getClist['State'];?>" <?php if(isset($filtvals['State']) && $filtvals['State']==$getClist['State']){echo "Selected='Selected'";}?>><?php  echo $getClist['State'];?></option>
            <?php }$e=error_get_last(); print_r($e); ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div>Native<br>
        <select name="NativeTown" id="native">
                <option value="Choose">Choose</option>

        <?php while($getClist=$getC->fetch_assoc()){?>
                <option value="<?php  echo $getClist['NativeTown'];?>" <?php if(isset($filtvals['NativeTown']) && $filtvals['NativeTown']==$getClist['NativeTown']){echo "Selected='Selected'";}?>><?php  echo $getClist['NativeTown'];?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>


    <div>Language<br>
        <!--<input type="text" name="native" id="native" Placeholder="Native Town" <?php //if(isset($filtvals['native'])){echo "Value ='$filtvals[native]'";}?>>-->
        <select name="Language" id="Language">
                <option value="Choose">Choose</option>

        <?php while($getClist=$getC->fetch_assoc()){?>
                <option value="<?php  echo $getClist['Language'];?>" <?php if(isset($filtvals['Language']) && $filtvals['Language']==$getClist['Language']){echo "Selected='Selected'";}?>><?php  echo $getClist['Language'];?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

RESULT
After City, other Select boxes do not get populated !

[image: After City, other Select boxes do not get populated !]

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and the results you are getting.

Comment: your `SELECT` queries are just impossible to return only `city` field rows. Dig into your php code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , I have mentioned that I have the listed columns with  data but the result is that the select boxes do not get populated for columns other than City

Comment: @TedoG above is exactly what I have in PHP code

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please check. I have updated everything you had asked. Do give me a solution now

Comment: This is why I find this forum pathetic sometimes. Downvotes galore (Shoot and Scoot ) ! But No  Solutions !

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved?

Comment: @jarlh Reason is, I want only DISTINCT values

Comment: I see, you want `SELECT DISTINCT`...

Comment: Yes, however, I have seen somewhere that "SELECT DISTINCT column_name" is same as "SELECT column_name GROUP BY column_name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change all your PHP code. You are triyng to fetch the query results one time for each column, and that is not possible. You have to do some thing like this:

```
$getC=$maindb->query("SELECT City, NativeTown, Language, State FROM candidates 
WHERE ApprovalCode!='' AND Gender='$gtype' 
ORDER BY City,NativeTown,State,Language ASC") or die("LIST ERROR :".$maindb->error);
data=[];
while($getClist=$getC->fetch_assoc()){
    data[]=[$getClist['City'].$getClist['State'],$getClist['NativeTown']]
}
```

So now you have an array with data. Now in the code you need to iterate over that array.

Comment: I did think about it, @nacho. But I wanted trying to fetch everything in one go. And thank you for pointing out that it is not possible. That is a real answer. Unlike the vain 'No-Solution-Down-Voters' !

Comment: And don't use the GROUP BY clause, you don't need it

Comment: Reason is, I want only DISTINCT values

Comment: So then use SELECT DISTINCT City, ... it's more efficient & clear

Comment: I have tried that too and  I have seen somewhere that "SELECT DISTINCT column_name" is same as "SELECT column_name GROUP BY column_name"